# Bash: Echo file contents precedes with counter

Tags: bash

I am looking for a `bash` script which reads the file content and it should echo the output as mentioned below:

Input File: `file.txt`

```
host1a

host2b

host3c

host4e
```

I want my output like:

```
--START--

opt1:host1a

opt2:host2b

opt3:host3c

opt4:host4e

--END--
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a many possibilities, try this way for example.

```
#!/bin/bash

opt="1";
while read line; 
do
    if [ ! -z "$line" ]
    then
            echo "opt$opt:$line"
            opt=$(($opt+1))
    fi

done <your_input_file.txt
```